# RPi running Alpine hangs every few days, only just managed to catch the CLI output. How do I investigate further? Can't find anything in journalctl

Tags: command-line, linux-kernel, alpine-linux

[image: CLI Output]

This is currently all I have to go on via plugging my normally headless Pi into a monitor before it hung entirely.  Looking in the journalctl logs after the fact provides no indication of anything being wrong at any point.

How do I determine what is causing this problem and why?

Comment: You've got a tainted kernel -usually you'd be asked to boot an untainted kernel to reproduce the issue in order to rule out lower-quality third party closed source drivers (e.g., nvidia, Mali drivers)

Comment: How does one un-taint a kernel?

Comment: Other than that, prime suspect on a pi is running out of RAM or reaching the end of life of the SD card (a medium never meant for the intense read/write cycles of a general purpose Linux)

Comment: most probably; don't load whatever proprietary kernels modules you load at boot!

Comment: I read about the problems with booting off an SD card, which is why I am booting from an SSD via the USB port.

Comment: That is important info and explains the tip line!

Answer (score 0):

> I am booting from an SSD via the USB port

When looking at the top line, it would seem your kernel has tasks (kswapd) that are blocked that basically only do block io - quite possibly the USB connection is unreliable, or your ssd goes to sleep and doesn't quite make it back up